# What meta tag yoast focus keyword insert to my page?

Tags: seo, php, meta-tags

What `meta tag` or `custom tag` yoast [focus keyword](https://yoast.com/focus-keyword/) insert to my page?

How to simulate that in a .php base website?
Because The Meta Keyword Tag Is No Longer Used by Google.

Comment: This is Yoast's own algorithm, not a meta tag, at work. It analyzes your pages based on keyword density and such, inside the tool itself. It doesn't insert anything into your page code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't insert any (meta) tag relating to the "focus keyword".

From my understanding of that article, the *focus keyword* is simply the keyword that you are targeting in your content. You change the "focus keyword" by changing your content. The Yoast tool simply helps you identify what that keyword might be and how to achieve it (by editing your content).

By itself, the Yoast tool doesn't actually *do* anything.

> Because The Meta Keyword Tag Is No Longer Used by Google.

Yes, there is no "magic" tag that identifies keywords. Google analyses your page *content* to identify the subject matter (and keywords).